# How to run a ec2 instance as subdomain in siteground?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have a Wordpress website with a GoDaddy domain being hosted on SiteGround using the nameservers. I am looking to switch to a React App which is currently running on an EC2 instance in AWS. I want to run the ec2 instance (aka the react app) on a subdomain like beta.domain.com inside SiteGround while still keeping the Wordpress website since its a part of my business. I tried creating a subdomain in SiteGround and then pointed it to my EC2 instance elastic IP (the public ipv4) using an A record but it is showing "This site can't be reached" error once I go to beta.domain.com.

What am I doing wrong? How do I run the EC2 instance in a subdomain hosted in SiteGround?

**EDIT**

Thank you, everyone, for your help. The problem was the SSL certificate for the HTTPS. The website wasn't coming on due to the HTTPS setup on the Nginx on the EC2 instance. After I put in the details of the certificate it runs properly with just the A record.

Comment: What port used by your react app on the EC2 instance?

Comment: it's running on port 3000 but reverse proxied to 80 using nginx

Comment: Alright, looking at Somangshu Goswami's answer and I think his answer will help you to get it to work, would definitely suggest option 2 so you will not have to worry about setting up and maintaining nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Any public address in the AWS environment are never accessible from outside the security groups. Even if you try to ssh from your own machine and if it is not in the inbound rule of the security group of your EC2 instance. I feel there are 3 ways out here.

1.) Adding an all traffic rule in your EC2 Security group inbound rule. This is not recommended as it opens all traffic to your machine.(additional tip: set up secure ssh key with the machine)

2.) Use an ELB to route traffic to your EC2 instance. ELB will provide you with a DNS record which can be used an a CNAME in godaddy(Point 3 shows how to map it as a A record in GoDaddy)

3.) Using Route 53 Hosted Zones - You could delegate your DNS to be managed by AWS Route 53. This way all traffic will be routed to your machine by AWS R53.

---

Another tip: Elastic IP can also be used which are like permanent static IP Addresses accessible from across internet. This provided a secure communication method to your instances.

Let me know what could be the favorable solution for you. I could help you out further

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered your domain name with Goaddy, you can create subdomain in Godaddy as CNAME and point it to static IP address of your ec2 instance. [Here](https://pk.godaddy.com/help/create-a-subdomain-4080) is a link to guide you.

Also your main domain name will point to your Wordpress website on SiteGround.

Now that you have EC2 instance, you can also run a [wordpress site on that instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html) if you like.